# Pandas Profiling - NameError: name 'pandas_profiling' is not defined

Tags: python, pandas, nameerror, pandas-profiling

Experts,

Here is my block of code and I am getting the below error.

```
import pandas 
import os
trainFile = r'C:\PythonProjects\sample.csv'
pwd = os.getcwd()
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(trainFile))
trainData = pandas.read_csv(os.path.basename(trainFile))
p=pandas_profiling.ProfileReport(trainData)
os.chdir(pwd)
```

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         6 trainData = pandas.read_csv(os.path.basename(trainFile))
>   ----> 7 p=pandas_profiling.ProfileReport(trainData)
>         8 os.chdir(pwd)

Can you provide your inputs/suggestions to resolve this error pls.
NameError: name 'pandas_profiling' is not defined

Answer (score 3):

Remember to run `import pandas_profiling` before using it.

This should work for those who want to use the latest version:

1. Run `pip uninstall pandas_profiling` or `conda uninstall pandas_profiling` from anaconda prompt/command prompt
2. Run `pip install https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling/archive/master.zip`

If you're using something like a Jupyter Notebook/Jupyter Lab, be sure to restart your kernel and re-import your packages.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `pip install pandas-profiling` command in a separate cell in the jupyter notebook just before importing all the packages.

After this re-start your kernel and re-run the whole notebook again. This should give you the required profile report.

Answer (score -1):

"pandas_profiling" comes as a pip packages.
Have you installed the package..?

```
pip install pandas-profiling
```

or maybe you have installed the package in some virtual environment, not in your complete path.

See the link [pandas-profiling](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pandas-profiling)

Comment: Yes I did check the installation using pip freeze command the package was installed successfully and I do not have a virtual environment. Is there a way I could provide the absolute path of this package in my program.

Comment: Yes. Pycharm removed the reference citing it could not able to locate the reference.